# Android Gradle Dependencies conflict with com.android.support:appcompat-v7

Tags: android, gradle, build, android-support-library

Basically I have Android app which uses 23.1.1 of the support library(com.android.support:appcompat-v7:) while I`m using a library which uses 25.0.0 version. Basically if I update the version and make it to be equal(the project one and the library one) I`m getting a lot of null pointer exceptions which is pretty strange because the app works pretty well at the current version(23.1.1). If I force the library to be using the version of the app - there is a compile error because a new things have been added with the new version(25.0.0). Is it possible somehow to say in the build.gradle let`s the app be using the 23.1.1 version of com.android.support:appcompat-v7: and the library to use its(25.0.0) version of com.android.support:appcompat-v7:?

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible somehow to say in the build.gradle let`s the app be using the 23.1.1 version of com.android.support:appcompat-v7: and the library to use its(25.0.0) version of com.android.support:appcompat-v7:?

No, because there is only copy of `appcompat-v7` in your app.

Comment: Ok, then is it possible to exclude the problematical .xml layout files from the library because the problem is only in them and I'm not usung these files in the app?

Comment: @user3703313: Only by forking and rebuilding the library. A far better solution is to fix the problems in your app that are preventing you from using modern versions of the Android Support Library artifacts. Staying with the old artifacts for some app that you're only fixing bugs on is fine. Staying with the old artifacts for an app that you are actively developing is not a good plan, as you will keep running into this problem.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much!I'm aware of most of the things which you mention and I will try tomorrow to fix the issues even that they are null pointer for example.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to remove your import of the 23.x.x of the support library .

The version of the support library that is present in your lib will be use .

Comment: I did both  - using the latest one and using the project's one, but no one of them fits for both (app and library)

Comment: Can you share the exception you get when you use the latest version , please ?